# portable conda environment as a binary tarball

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to build a portable `conda` environment.
So we can tarball and distribute it to another server or many servers later.
Place where we build environment and where it'll be deployed later are two different places.
I noticed that `conda create` and `conda install` both hard-code environment location into shebang of all the installed scripts under `environment_path\bin` - is there is a way to override that?

We have to use deployment location and not build location for that environment in shebang `bin/` scripts.

Also created https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7861

Disclaimer: I'm aware of option of rebuilding environment using exported yaml file, but this is not what we're looking here. We want to make conda environment redistributable / portable as a binary tarball - deployment location is known, but it's not the same as environment build location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found `conda-pack` that seems address this issue directly

https://github.com/conda/conda-pack

> `conda-pack` is a command line tool for creating relocatable conda
>   environments. This is useful for deploying code in a consistent
>   environment, **potentially in a location where python/conda isn't
>   already installed**.

Documentation: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

**Use Cases**:

- **Bundling an application with its environment for deployment**
- Packaging a conda environment for usage with Apache Spark when deploying on
  YARN (see here for more information).
- Packaging a conda environment for deployment on Apache YARN. One way to do this is to use Skein.
- **Archiving an environment in a functioning state**.

**Update**: Some other of our PySpark applications are using a `conda` environment on a location that's available on all Hadoop nodes (NFS mount) and it works very well for some conda environments that don't have a ton of dependencies.

Comment: I'm doing similar implementation and wondering if you have seen any issues till now implementing this approach? If so, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are saved in `<conda_root>/pkgs`. You can copy these files (as well as the anaconda installer script) to your deployment server, install anaconda, and running `conda install <path_to_pkgs>/*.bz2`.

Comment: Can you please bring some light what is "anaconda installer script" ? It seems I also have to deploy something like `miniconda` to have `conda` available there? That servers may not have any anaconda/conda/python traces before, so the hope was if we could to use this portable conda tarbal, unzip it and it'll be whole python environment on its own. Thank you.

Comment: https://conda.io/miniconda.html

It's a self-contained installer. You could easily set up a shell script to do all this.