# Moving Anaconda installation from one user account to another

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, virtualenv

I apologize if this is not the correct site for this.  If it is not, please let me know.

Here's some background on what I am attempting.  We are working on a series of chat bots that will go into production.  Each of them will run on a  environment in Anaconda.  However, our setup uses tensorflow, which uses gcc to be compiled, and compliance has banned compilers from production.  In addition, compliance rules also frown on us using pip or conda install in production.

As a way to get around this, I'm trying to tar the Anaconda 3 folder and move it into prod, with all dependencies already compiled and installed.  However, the accounts between environments have different names, so this requires me to go into the bin folder (at the very least; I'm sure I will need to change them in the lib and pckg folders as well) and use `sed -i` to rename the hard coded paths to point from `\home\<dev account>\anaconda` to `\home\<prod account>\anaconda`, and while this seems to work, its also a good way to mangle my installation.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any good way to transfer anaconda from one user to another, without having to use `sed -i` on these paths? I've already read that Anaconda itself does not support this, but I would like your input.
2. Is there any way for me to install anaconda in dev so the scripts in it are either hard coded to use the production account name in their paths, or to use `~`.
3. If I must continue to use `sed`, is there anything critical I should be aware of? For example, when I use `grep <dev account> *`, I will some files listed as `binary file matches`.  DO I need to do anything special to change these?

And once again, I am well aware that I should just create a new Anaconda installation on the production machine, but that is simply not an option.

Edit:
So far, I've changed the conda.sh and conda.csh files in /etc, as well as the conda, activate, and deactivate files in the root bin.  As such, I'm able to activate and deactivate my environment on the new user account.  Also, I've changed the files in the bin folder under the bot environment.  Right now, I'm trying to train the bot to test if this works, but it keeps failing and stating that a custom action does not exist in the the list.  I don't think that is related to this, though.

Edit2:
I've confirmed that the error I was getting was not related to this.  In order to get the bot to work properly with a ported version of Anaconda, all I had to change was the the conda.sh and conda.csh files in /etc so their paths to python use ~, do the same for the activate and deactivate files in /bin, and change the shebang line in the conda file in /bin to use the actual account name.  This leaves every other file in /bin and lib still using the old account name in their shebang lines and other variable that use the path, and yet the bots work as expected.  By all rights, I don't think this should work, but it does.

Comment: Build your environments in a chroot or a docker container with the same paths used in production ... and talk your ops team into a decent deployment pipeline ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [portable conda environment as a binary tarball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844040/portable-conda-environment-as-a-binary-tarball)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda is touchy about path names. They're obviously inserted into scripts, but they may be inserted into binaries as well. Some approaches that come to mind are:

1. Use Docker images in production. When building the image:

   - Install compilers as needed.
   - Build your stuff.
   - Uninstall the compilers and other stuff not needed at runtime.
   - **Squash the image into a single layer.**
     This makes sure that the uninstalled stuff is actually gone.
2. Install Anaconda into the *directory* `\home\<prod account>\anaconda` on the development or build systems as well. Even though *accounts* are different, there should be a way to create a user-writeable directory in the same location.

   - Even better: Install Anaconda into a directory `\opt\anaconda` in all environments. Or some other directory that does not contain a username.
3. If you cannot get a directory outside of the user home, negotiate for a symlink or junction ([mklink.exe /d or /j](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)) at a fixed path `\opt\anaconda` that points into the user home.

   - If necessary, play it from the QA angle: Differing directory paths in production, as compared to all other environments, introduce a risk for bugs that can only be detected and reproduced in production. The QA or operations team should *mandate* that all applications use fixed paths everywhere, rather than make an exception for yours ;-)
4. Build inside a Docker container using directory `\home\<prod account>\anaconda`, then export an archive and run on the production system without Docker.

   - It's generally a good idea to build inside a reproducible Docker environment, even if you can get a fixed path without an account name in it.
5. Bundle your whole application as a pre-compiled Anaconda package, so that it can be installed without compilers.

   - *That doesn't really address your problem though, because even `conda install` is frowned upon in production. But it could simplify building Docker images without squashing.*

I've been building Anaconda environments inside Docker and running them on bare metal in production, too. But we've always made sure that the paths are identical across environments. I found mangling the paths too scary to even try. Life has become much simpler when we switched to Docker images everywhere. But if you have to keep using `sed`... Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need : [pip2pi](https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi).

**This only works for pip compatible packages.**

As I understand you need to move your whole setup as previously compiled as `.tar.gz` file, then here are a few things you could try:

1. Create a `requirements.txt`. These packages can help :
   a. [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

   ```
   $ pipreqs /home/project/location
   Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
   ```

   b. [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/).
2. Then, install `pip2pi`

   `$ pip install pip2pi`

   ```
   $ pip2tgz packages/ foo==1.2
   ...
   $ ls packages/
   foo-1.2.tar.gz
   bar-0.8.tar.gz
   ```

`pip2tgz` passes package arguments directly to pip, so packages can be specified in any format that pip recognises:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
foo==1.2
http://example.com/baz-0.3.tar.gz
$ pip2tgz packages/ -r requirements.txt bam-2.3/
...
$ ls packages/
foo-1.2.tar.gz
bar-0.8.tar.gz
baz-0.3.tar.gz
bam-2.3.tar.gz
```

After getting all `.tar.gz` files, `.tar.gz` files can be turned into PyPI-compatible "simple" package index using the `dir2pi` command:

```
$ ls packages/
bar-0.8.tar.gz
baz-0.3.tar.gz
foo-1.2.tar.gz
$ dir2pi packages/
$ find packages/
packages/
packages/bar-0.8.tar.gz
packages/baz-0.3.tar.gz
packages/foo-1.2.tar.gz
packages/simple
packages/simple/bar
packages/simple/bar/bar-0.8.tar.gz
packages/simple/baz
packages/simple/baz/baz-0.3.tar.gz
packages/simple/foo
packages/simple/foo/foo-1.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

> but they may be inserted into binaries as well

I can confirm that some packages have hard-coded the absolute path (including username) into the compiled binary. But if you restrict usernames to have the same length, you can apply `sed` on both binary and text files to make almost everything work as perfect.

On the other hand, if you copy the entire folder and use `sed` to replace usernames on only text files, you can run most of the installed packages. However, operations involving run-time compilation might fail, one example is installing a new package that requires compilation during installation.